# Linked List : Inserting from the Beginning

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I have 2 ways of inserting a node from the beginning. The first one works while the second one doesn't. Can you explain me why?

(The list already has some elements and the head is the head node of that list)

And I have initialized head like this

```
list *head = new list;
```

---

```
 void push(list **head, int info)
   {
   list *node=new list;
   node->data=info;
   node->next=*head;
   *head=node;
   }
   push(&head,5);
```

and the next one is

```
void push(list *head, int info)
   {
   list *node=new list;
   node->data=info;
   node->next=head;
   head=node;
   }
   push(head,5);
```

Comment: what do you mean with "does not work" ? your second one passes the `head` pointer by value, so `head = node` wont have any effect, is it that what you mean?

Comment: In the 2nd case, you pass the `head` (which is a pointer) but not the address of it. Thus, the change of `head`happens "locally" in `push()` but not on the "original" `head`.

Comment: By default arguments are passed *by value*, which means they are copied. Now if you modify a copy, the original will not change, right? So what do you think happens when you, in the second function, modify the *copy* (`head`) of a variable?

Comment: btw instead of describing preconditions via text you should provide a [mcve]

Comment: If you change the signature of 2nd `push()` to `void push(list *&head, int info)` it will work as well (as you pass then `head` as reference instead as value).

Comment: @Scheff : Just to clarify my understanding I have initialized head like this `list *head = new list;` .  So `*head` is the node and `head` is the address of my head node. Am I correct till here?.

Comment: Yepp...........

Comment: Be carefully: `list *head` as well as `list* head` denotes a variable `head` with type pointer to `list`. Here `*` is part of type. Do not confuse with the unary operator `*` if you access the contents of your pointer variable with `*head` (in an expression).

Comment: I sometimes read a comment of Ken Thompson (one of the inventors of C) that they thought it would be a good idea to use the `*` in the declaration the same way (and the same literals) like in the expressions/statements. However, due to this, I (and probably many others) needed a certain time until recognizing the difference...

Comment: That's is how it's done in C. Why aren't the functions members of class List? Your list class seems to be a node class.

Comment: @Scheff It has noting to do with understanding pointers. It's about understanding how it is done in C++.

Comment: @Scheff I give him a chance to learn C++ and not C. See BS key note on cppcon.

Comment: Okay Now I understood it. Thank you "everyone"..and especially @Scheff

Answer (score 1):

The first receives a *pointer to* the head pointer, while the second version receives a *copy* of the head pointer. Therefore, the first version is able to modify the head pointer, while the second can only modify the local copy here: `head = node`.

To make the second version work, you can accept the `head` pointer by reference: just choose the function signature to `void push(list * & head, int info)` *(note the &)*.

You may want to read more on [pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/book/pointers) and [references](http://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/reference).

Answer (score 0):

Inserting a node to the front of a linked list requires you to update the `head` pointer i.e. the address of the first node.

Your broken implementation never updates the head pointer outside the function, only the local copy of it, so the implementation is incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

the following code samples show you the basic of passing argument by value and by reference:

by pointer:

```
foo(int* ref)
{
     *ref = 1;
}

void main(void)
{
    int bar = 0;
    foo(&bar);
    print("%d",bar); //print 1
}
```

by value:

```
// this 'int val' will be created on the stack when the function get called and 
// the value passed to the function will be copied to the temporary val argument
foo(int val)
{
     val = 1;
}

void main(void)
{
    int bar = 0;
    foo(bar);
    print("%d",bar); //print 0
}
```

In the first example we pass a pointer to an int (that contain the address of **'bar'** from the main) and thus when we modifies the variable pointed by the reference we actually modify the **'bar'** from the main.

However in the second example we pass the value of **'bar'** to be copied in a temporary variable called **'val'** (**'val'** only exist in function **'foo'** and is not the same as **'bar'** in the  main) thus when we modify it, nothing is visible from the main.

Your examples are identical to this except that for you:

- 'int bar' is 'list* head'
- 'int *ref' is 'list** head'
- 'int val' is 'list* head'

Hope you got the idea. If not you read about pointers and references, not the easiest notion in C/C++.

Comment: I understand your example completely. I knew about your example before as well but what is confusing me is when you're passing by value you're passing a variable so it is getting copied. But I am sending the address of the variable in `push(head,5);` Just like you passed by reference in the pointer case. So whatever change happens it should happen to the real head as well right?..

Comment: Okay Now I understood it. Thanks

Comment: Because you want to modify a pointer then you need to pass the address of this pointer and your then got a pointer to pointer to list